# What is the equivalent of Android's weightsum in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, android-layout-weight, ios-autolayout

I have a bunch of UIButton's I want them to get equally distributed on the screen for screensizes. Is it possible to achieve it without using AutoLayout? My view fits perfectly on a 640*960 screen, where as if its larger than that there is empty space in the bottom. So is there any equivalent of weightsum in iOS?
 I have attached two images that shows how the view looks on a 640*960 **(second image)** and 640*1136 **(First image)** screen.

[image: 640*1136]

[image: 640*960]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you choose auto layout for that kind of behaviour. In your case it is pretty straightforward constraints that are easily set in IB. If you prefer setting it from code, us Visual Language.

Also, but as to me, it is a bit of overkill, you may use UICollectionView

Comment: UICollectionView is a good Idea. Thanks. Ill try that out and update.

Comment: @ManjuBasha, have you succeed?

Comment: Yes kind of. When it comes to 640*960 screen it becomes scrollable. The buttons arent getting resized. I mean they dont fit exactly in the screen

Comment: @ManjuBasha, yes, it does. You'll need to adjust your buttons sizes to the sizes of screen on your own. In delegate method `- collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` you can use `collectionView.bounds.size` to know, in what area happens layout.

Comment: The thing is that my whole app is already built without auto layout / layout constraints. I cant enable auto layout for just one viewcontroller in my storyboard. That is why i am trying not to use  auto layout / layout constraints

Comment: I adjusted UICollectionViewFlowLayout itemsize and its working perfectly on all screens. Thank you so much for suggesting me to use UICollectionView :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) which lets you easily lay out views without worrying about Auto Layout (which it does use internally).

Interface Builder in Xcode 7 has a useful embed in stack view option which should make it easy to do this.

Comment: UIStackView is aviable in iOS 9.0, which is beta now. Not the best idea to use it in production code